# Why do we seek to find a model that approximates all data instead of finding a function that fits all data?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, predictive-models, modeling, nonlinear-regression

I tried to learn the principle idea of regressions. As I understand, the aim is to find a model that represents the relation between the x numbers and the y numbers, so that we can understand the patterns based on this model.

Let's talk about non-linear regression. Its aim is to find a model that is close to all data points. After finding this model, let's suppose that its curve is a polynomial function. As I've seen, this polynomial function never fits all the data perfectly, but it is just close to them. I don't know why we want to do that instead of finding a curve that fits all data exactly, for example, why we can't use the Lagrange interpolation formula to find the exact function that represents the data.

I understand that the function obtained using the Lagrange interpolation formula may not be effective in accurately predicting new values for different numbers, and therefore cannot be relied upon for decision-making. However, I am wondering also how a model that is not accurate like it, can still give us confidence in its predictive values.

$L(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} y_i \prod_{\substack{j=0 \\ j\neq i}}^{n} \frac{x - x_j}{x_i - x_j}$(Lagrange interpolation formula)

Comment: Why be a slave to a perfect fit in situations where you know the data are measured with error or subject to other forms of variation?  That's called *overfitting* and usually leads to bad results: [search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=overfit*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data had no noise then Lagrange multipliers would be the way to go in many cases. The problem is that most of our data has noise. So if you fit perfectly to data then you fit perfectly to noise too. Noise gets into your model parameters.

When we use regression models we designate a special place in our models where we hope to push the noise into. That way model parameters have chance to not be too noisy, thus reducing overfitting. The problem with overfitting is that when the noise is in parameters, it will also propagate into our predictions.

Answer (score 0):

you raise a good point. There is no set-in-stone reason for us to prefer a polynomial function over the lagrange function if we know nothing about the relationship between x and y. However, we do have assumptions regarding this relationship that seem to be beneficial. For example, we make the assumption that the relationship between x and y in the past is somewhat similar to the relationship in the future. Another assumption that is often made is that a polynomial function is more likely than a lagrange function. This is related to the idea of Occam's Razor.

Comment: I suspect most people wouldn't believe *either* type of function is likely at all, except in some very special circumstances (largely confined to theoretical physics).  There's a more fundamental problem: Lagrange interpolation exhausts all the available degrees of freedom in the model, making it the *least parsimonious possible* (there's where Occam's Razor applies) as well as making it impossible to assess the uncertainty in the fit (which is perhaps of even greater importance).